# Is Cornhole on-topic?

Tags: discussion, top-7, on-topic

Prompted by: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/186/variation-on-rules-for-cornhole-which-involves-two-boards

If [cornhole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornhole) is on-topic, then what about games like shuffleboard, horseshoes or bowling? However if cornhole is off-topic, what about games like crokinole or PitchCar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm inclined to say cornhole is off-topic; I would not consider it to be a board game. I would say crokinole and PitchCar are on-topic, though it's certainly getting into a gray area and I'm not sure where I would draw the line.

Comment: I would agree -- technically cornhole is a game played with boards, but it's not a board game to me.  If you can't sit down at a table and play it, it's not a board or card game.

Comment: +1 Pitchcar is border line, but still just in. Like the 'If you can't sit down at a table and play it, it's not a board or card game.'

Answer (score 5):

Off-topic. I would say the essential differentiating characteristic is that all of these games are purely about physical skills, and to me this site is about games that have a substantial strategy or thinking component.

So to me, shuffleboard, horseshoes, bowling, cornhole, and even crokinole are all out. I'm not sure how PitchCar works exactly - I looked it up on boardgamegeek but that didn't help. So I'll reserve judgement there.

Comment: I'm guessing there won't be much dissent about Cornhole being off-topic. However, crokinole and PitchCar are more controversial. We might need a question specifically about them.

Comment: See the comments on [this answer by Brian Campbell](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/174/if-you-cant-sit-down-at-a-table-and-play-it-its-not-a-board-or-card-game-goo/180#180) to a different question for a slightly more nuanced point of view in this discussion.